# how do I use the Rails.logger from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3

I nside a html.erb, I want to use the logger

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $j(function(){

    $j('#AddQuestion').click(function(){
     //Send and http transaction to the server to get the address
      $j('#dialog').dialog(
        {buttons:{OK:function (event) {
                say('You clicked the ' + $(event.target).text() + ' button' );
              },  No:function (event) {
                say('You clicked the ' + $(event.target).text() + ' button' );
              }
                }
         });

      $j('#dialog').dialog('open');

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just have this use `console.log` or an `alert`? I don't see why this has to go through `Rails.logger`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
# controllers/logs_controller.rb
class LogsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    logger.debug params['message']
    render :nothing => true
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
map.logs "logs", :controller => 'logs', :action => 'create', :conditions => {:method => :post}

# js
$.post('/logs', {message: 'Your log message'})
```

Comment: you are absolutly right the way to do it is to use the firebug conosole inside the java script like: console.log("whatever");

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between **server-side code** (code that runs on the web server, e.g. Ruby/Rails) and **client-side code** (code that runs on the web browser of the user, e.g. JavaScript).

The only way that JavaScript can use a Ruby method is by making a request (typically via AJAX) to the server, and having the server invoke Ruby code in response.

Comment: The javascript is running in the server what I did was to use the firebug conosole inside the java script like: console.log("whatever");

Answer (score 1):

Phrogz is correct.  [Here's an example](http://gaertig.pl/blog/en/2009/12/javascript-logging-to-server-using-ajax-jquery-rails.html) of using JQuery's XHR functionality to shoot messages over to a customised logging class.  Just utilising `Rails.logger` instead of this custom class is a cinch.